# Check login status in routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an Angular project but I'm having a little problem and I'd appreciate any help because I'm really lost. Basically I need to check if a user is logged in, and if he is, he should not be allowed to access a certain view/route, here's the code I'm using for this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/registroVisitante', {
        template: '<registro-visitante></registro-visitante>',
        resolve: {
          "check": function(Auth, $location) {
            console.log(Auth.isLoggedIn());
            if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
              alert("Access allowed");
            } else {
              $location.path('/'); //redirect user to home.
              alert("Access denied");
            }
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

The problem itself is that, this is actually working, but only when I try to access the route via an anchor click or ng-click or whatever, however, when I type the route in the address bar it lets me access but it shouldn't, anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Is `Auth` a service that queries a back-end?

Comment: Yes, it is, first time asking a question here so I probably left out little details that help you guys

Comment: If you could post what the `Auth` service is, or at least what the `isLoggedIn` function is doing, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/registroVisitante', {
                template: '<registro-visitante></registro-visitante>',
                resolve: {
                    "check": function (Auth, $location) {
                        Auth.isLoggedIn(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response) {
                                $location.path('/'); //redirect user to home.
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

The problem was that it was an asynchronous request and maybe when it got to the if it was undefined.